# Doubts with gradle closure

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, closures

I wish to create the version and sha files for my project. I am using spring boot's repackage method to build my jar.

```
subproject.tasks.create(name: 'writeVersion') {
    new File("$rootDir/upload/").mkdirs()

    def sha = calcSha1(new File("$rootDir/deploy/${jar.archiveName}"));
    def gitId = grgit.head().abbreviatedId

    def shaFile = new File("$rootDir/upload/$rootProject.serviceName-$gitId-$sha"+".sha256");
    def versionFile = new File("$rootDir/upload/version.txt");

    shaFile.text = $sha;
    versionFile.text = "$rootProject.serviceName-$gitId-$sha"
}
```

Thanks to [dagezi](https://gist.github.com/dagezi/9594839)

I have the following:

```
def calcSha1 = { file ->
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    file.eachByte 4096, {bytes, size ->
        md.update(bytes, 0, size);
    }
    return md.digest().collect {String.format "%02x", it}.join();
}
```

Everytime I try to run the task, I get an error saying that the jar is not found. I understand that this happens because it is trying to generate the SHA at configuration time, but not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
subprojects {
   task writeVersion << {
      new File("$rootDir/upload/").mkdirs()

      def sha = calcSha1(new File("$rootDir/deploy/${jar.archiveName}"));
      def gitId = grgit.head().abbreviatedId

      def shaFile = new File("$rootDir/upload/$rootProject.serviceName-$gitId-$sha"+".sha256");
      def versionFile = new File("$rootDir/upload/version.txt");

      shaFile.text = $sha;
      versionFile.text = "$rootProject.serviceName-$gitId-$sha"
   }
}
```

The `<<` (left-shift) operator is equivalent to putting your statements inside of a `doLast { }` closure. These blocks are run in the execution phase.